# Delete duplicate characters from string

Tags: java, duplicates

I'm trying to delete duplicate characters from a string. For example if I enter the string `abaqueru` it should give me `bqer` with duplicate characters `a` and `u` deleted. However, instead the result is an unnecessary loop. Here is the code:

```
public class question {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String s = "abaqueru";

   calculate(s);
    // TODO code application logic here
}

public static void calculate(String s){
     String result;

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
           char c = s.charAt(i);
           char temp;
           temp=c;
           for(int j = 1; j < s.length(); j++)
                {

                   char x = s.charAt(j);
                   if(temp==x){
                       s=s.replaceAll(""+temp,"");
                       calculate(s);
                   }



                }

            System.out.println(s);
        }

}
```

Comment: don't change your question completely  .ask new one if you have a another question

Comment: Sorry, i didnt know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go with Suresh Atta's Answer which was leading to stack overflow error.
I also checked your logic. Have made some necessary changes

```
public class Question {




    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String s = "abaqueru";

       calculate(s);
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

    public static void calculate(String s){
         String result;

            for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            {
               char c = s.charAt(i);

               char temp;
               temp=c;
               for(int j = i+1; j < s.length(); j++)
                    {

                       char x = s.charAt(j);
                       if(temp==x){

                          s=s.replaceAll(""+temp, "");

                           break;
                         //  calculate(s);
                       }



                    }


            }

            System.out.println(s);

    }

}
```

However this can be further customized to achive performance in terms of space and time. Infact, more simpler logic can be used :)

Answer (score 7):

`String` are immutable in java. After replaceall, you need to assign it back

```
s=s.replaceAll(""+temp,"");
```

If you didn't assign it back, the loop goes on forever.

That solves the stackoverflow error, I didn't concentrate on your actual logic :)

Comment: I corrected it thanks but i think i have algorithm problems also that taking me unnecessarry loops.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely go with Suresh Atta's answer! However, I figured I'd help glance over your code to help you find where some of your mistakes were.

I just glanced over your logic in the code though, and there is definitely some stuff worth glancing over. The most notable is that `j` is never used in the inner-for-loop. In fact, if you are using an IDE, it should warn you that `j` is never used.

**UPDATE**: Also, consider using [`String.valueOf(char c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char)) instead of the                        `s=s.replaceAll(""+temp,"");`
call you have in the `if(temp==x)` condition. That is, I assume that is so you could cast the character to a String? Then you can use String.append(), which you can read about on the link I sent you!

Comment: Yes, In there if i found any letter duplication in string, I change that duplicated letter with ""(space). and i use   // ""+temp // for string parse

Comment: If you don't use `j` in the inner for loop, all 3 character variables will be the same. Notice that you are grabbing the same character each time through the inner for loop, thus comparing it to a character it is guaranteed to be equal to. In other words, you are grabbing the character (at location `i`) `j` times.

Comment: Also, any particular reason why you went with a recursive solution this way?

Comment: I replace i with j in second loop and I dont know how many different repeated letter in string so i decide to use recursion.